# traefik 2.0 could not capture network in kubernetes cluster from cloud service LBS

Tags: kubernetes

I am deploy traefik 2.0 in kubernetes cluster using deployment type,  now the traefik service ip in kubernetes v1.16.0 cluster is: `10.96.0.15`, I can access the kuberentes servcie in kubernetes node using this command:

```
curl -v -k --header 'Host:apollo.xxx.net' http://10.96.0.15
```

now my user access traffic was received from  cloud service(alicloud) loadbalancer, and forward to internal ip, must the node install nginx to receive the traffic and forward to traefik? is it possible to forward the traefik from cloud service loadbalancer to kubernetes traefik ip?

Answer (score 0):

If you deployment traefik 2.X using kubernetes deployment type, the traefik default not listening on host machine.

- first way you can add nginx in your machine and forward data to traefik
- second way make traefik listening in some ports on your hostmachine, and lsb forward data to hostmachine's ports

if you want traefik listening on host machine, add config in your deployment yaml:

```
hostNetwork: true
```

I choose second way.After added config,using this command to see if it take effect in your host machine:

```
sudo lsof -i:{port}
```